# Rank and unipotent support

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, deligne-lusztig-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group of Lie type. I would like to be able to compute the rank (introduced by Howe and Gurevich in "Small representations of finite classical groups") of an irreducible representation of $G$.

For unipotent representations, is there a way to go from its "symbol" to the rank (maybe going through the unipotent support)?

For arbitrary irreducible representations, how could the Lusztig bijection be used to reduce the problem to unipotent representations?

In Howe and Gurevich's paper, they display tables with ranks of representations so there must be a way to do explicit computations. I hope someone can point out a reference. Thank you in advance.